# changing pixel values through direct access + opencv

Tags: visual-c++, opencv

Is there any problem in this code where I am just trying to subtract the pixel values of images through direct access of pixels ..... Am assuming that the images are of same height and width ... Whenever I run the program I am getting completely black picture.....

```
IplImage * img3 = cvCreateImage(cvSize(img1->height,img1->width),IPL_DEPTH_32F,3);
// img2 and img1 both are IplImage pointers
cvZero(img3);
long value;
for ( int row = 0 ; row < img2->height * img2->width ; row ++ ){
    value = &((uchar*)(img1->imageData))[row] - &((uchar*)(img2->imageData))[row] ; 
    img3->imageData[row] = value;
```

Answer (score 0):

1) img2->height * img2->width calculate as constant before loop

2)
I dont understand this line
&((uchar*)(img1->imageData))[row] - &((uchar*)(img2->imageData))[row] - are you subtracting pointer from another pointer? Why?
value = img1->imageData[row] - img2->imageData[row]; should do the trick

3) you can not subtract RGB values by subtracting pixel values (if that is your goal)

4) if img3->imageData is *char, then you should multiply row * 4.

Comment: Could you tell me why 3rd point would not work ? the RGB values are stored at that pixel coordinate ... So in imagedata the values are stored according to some format of pixel coordinates say r0,g0,b0,r1 ... etc ... If i just subtract each of them with the other would'nt it work ?